# InvalidCastException while casting to OrganizationServiceContext

Tags: c#, generics, casting, microsoft-dynamics

I have a early bound class generated by CrmSvcUtil:

```
public partial class CustomerCrmServiceContext : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext
{
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then I have a class like this (short version):

```
public abstract class PluginClass<T, C> : PluginClassBase<T> where T : Entity where C : OrganizationServiceContext
{
        protected new C ServiceContext;

        protected PluginClass(IOrganizationService service, ITracingService tracer) : base(service, tracer)
        {
            ServiceContext = (C)base.ServiceContext;
        }
}
```

And the Base class like this:

```
public abstract class PluginClassBase: IDisposable
{
    ...
    ...
    protected readonly OrganizationServiceContext ServiceContext;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am using this class like this:

```
public class DoWomethingWorkerPlugin : PluginClass<account, CustomerCrmServiceContext>
{
  ...
}
```

My Problem is the following statement:

```
ServiceContext = (C)base.ServiceContext;
```

This throws an InvalidCastException saying:

> "Unable to cast object of type
> 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext' to type
> 'Customer.DataModel.CustomerCrmServiceContext"

I'm confused since the generated class "CustomerCrmServiceContext" has the base type "OrganizationServiceContext" and therefore the cast should work.

Does anybody have an idea what can cause an InvalidCastException when base type is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a `CustomerCrmServiceContext` is an `OrganizationServiceContext`, the opposite isn't true, which is why you're getting the exception.

A cast cannot magically change an object's type at runtime.

By using a cast, your essentially telling the compiler *"Although you think this object is `SomeBaseType`, I know that, at runtime, it will always be an instance of `SomeDerivedType` so please treat it as such"*.

If it transpires that at runtime, the object isn't the type that you have tried to cast to, you will get an `InvalidCastException`, and an `OrganizationServiceContext` isn't a `CustomerCrmServiceContext`.

Comment: @PaulRichardson `CustomerCrmServiceContext` is a more specific type. It will have additional behaviour to `OrganizationServiceContext` and there is no way for the compiler to know how to convert an instance of `OrganizationServiceContext` to an instance of `CustomerCrmServiceContext`, unless you define a custom conversion operator. When you use an instance of `CustomerCrmServiceContext` in place of a `OrganizationServiceContext` (substitutability), the runtime type does not change, but the compiler knows it implements all the behaviour of `OrganizationServiceContext`.